# CKEditor autogrow sets height to 0 when editor initially hidden

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

We are upgrading XPages application to version 12.0.2. The CKEditor version shipped with the platform has changed to 4.18 (from 4.5.6.1).

Now, when the CKEditor is initially hidden, e.g. in a hidden Bootstrap tab, the height is set to 0.
[image: ckeditorsample]

We could set the autoGrow_onStartup to false, but it would stop the autogrow also in scenarios where it works fine as it's in a reusable component. The autoGrow_minHeight is not set, so the default should be used.

I have checked CKEditor and autogrow code and it seems that it does not detect the height of the content, so the variable is set to "auto", which is converted to NaN numeric value. Later on, the code calls resize(..,NaN,..). The previous version ignored the NaN, but now it's converted to 0 - probably by

```
height = convertCssUnitToPx( height );
```

Currently, the only solution I see is to create an own autogrow version that would handle the NaN height and convert it to the default height.

Does anyone have a better idea? Thanks.

Comment: This issue started with 12.0.2 - it is solved for most browsers with FP3 (but I still have an issue with Mac OS 14.2.1 and Chrome - ARM). I'll sent you a link to a test app. that you can try for your environment...

Comment: Oh, by the way the same issue is for 9.0.1 FP10 HF1042 - but it is wrong for all browsers....

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger autogrow when the editor becomes visible by using an [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

1. Add an onClientLoad event handler to a nearest container element, in my case it's in a Custom Control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:inputRichText id="${compositeData.field.fieldName}" readonly="${compositeData.field.readOnly || ((compositeData.field.fieldName == 'Body') and formContext.isBodyLocked)}"  
        htmlConversionWarning="noWarning" styleClass="times-12">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:"#{"+formContext.dataSourceName+"."+compositeData.field.fieldName+"}"}]]></xp:this.value>
        
        <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="fontSize_sizes" 
                value="8/8pt;9/9pt;10/10pt;11/11pt;12/12pt;14/14pt;16/16pt;18/18pt;20/20pt;22/22pt;24/24pt;26/26pt;28/28pt;36/36pt;48/48pt;72/72pt" />
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="toolbar" value="${compositeData.field.toolbar}" /> <!-- Slim, Medium (default), Large, Full -->
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="skin" value="moono-lisa,moono-lisa" />
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="tabSpaces" value="4" />
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="contentsCss" value="CKStyles.css" />
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="removePlugins" value="ibmsametimeemoticons" />
            
            <!-- Set height, if provided -->
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="height" value="${javascript:'' + compositeData.field.size}" loaded="${compositeData.field.size > 0}" />
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="autoGrow_minHeight" value="${javascript:'' + compositeData.field.size}" loaded="${compositeData.field.size > 0}" />
        </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        
    </xp:inputRichText>
    
    <!-- When initially hidden editor becomes visible, trigger autogrow -->
    <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false" script="attachVisibilityObserver(thisEvent.target)" />

</xp:view>
```

2. Define the function in some linked javascript file:

```
/* Attach an intersection observer to trigger autogrow on CKEditor instances that were initially hidden and became zero height */
function attachVisibilityObserver(element) {
    new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, observer) {
        entries.forEach(function(entry) {
            if(entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                var textArea = element.querySelector("textarea");
                if (textArea) {
                    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[textArea.id];
                    // Trying to exec autogrow throws errors if editor is not ready yet. This happens on page load 
                    // when editor is already visible, but those are  initialized properly anyway
                    if (editor && editor.status === "ready") {
                        editor.execCommand('autogrow');
                    }
                    observer.disconnect();
                }
            }
        });
    }).observe(element);
}
```

This will (re-)trigger CKEditor's autogrow plugin when the editor becomes visible. I'm using it in tabs, but should equally work with accordions, collapsible sections, etc